# angular 4: load components one by one

Tags: angular, asynchronous, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm using Ionic 3 with based on angular 4 framework. And I need to know if I have multiple children components can I load them asynchronously, one by one:

1. Load parent;
2. Load first child;
3. When first child loaded, load second child;
4. When second child loaded, load third child
5. and so on

For example I have a parent component `app.module.ts` with children:

```
@NgModule({
declarations: [
    AppComponentPage
],
imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(AppComponentPage),
    ChildOneComponentModule,
    ChildTwoComponentModule,
    ChildThreeComponentModule,
    ChildFourComponentModule,
],
entryComponents: [
    AppComponentPage
]})
export class AppComponentPageModule {}
```

and `app.component.ts`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
//import all child components

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent-component',
  template: `
      <child1-component></child1-component>
      <child2-component></child2-component>
      <child3-component></child3-component>
      <child4-component></child4-component>
  `
 })
 export class AppComponentPage {

    //HOW TO LOAD?

 }
```

Comment: make use of setTimeout and ngIf

Comment: What do you mean by "loading a component asynchronously"? Do you mean "displaying them one after the other, every N seconds"? Something else?

Comment: What do you want to load? What does "one by one". What knowledge do you expect to gain when loading them "one by one"?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, Ok, guys, sorry for confusing, I edited a bit my question

Comment: What does "child loaded" mean exactly?

Comment: I updated my answer. Instead of `Observable.interval` you would need some way to notify the parent from the child when to add the next children. You can use a shared service for that (there are lots of answers about communication using a shared service).

Comment: Well I need that `ngOnInit` in first child finished work and only then I could start load next component

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In each of your child components, add an output:

```
@Output
initialized = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
```

and emit an event when you decide that the component is initialized (or loaded, as your question says), and that the next one can thus be displayed:

```
ngOnInit() {
  ...
  this.initialized.emit(true);
}
```

In the parent component, have a counter:

```
counter = 0;
```

Increment the counter every time a component is initialized, and don't display a component until the counter is allowing it to be displayed:

```
<child1-component (initialized)="counter++"></child1-component>
<child2-component (initialized)="counter++" *ngIf="counter > 0"></child2-component>
<child3-component (initialized)="counter++" *ngIf="counter > 1"></child3-component>
<child4-component (initialized)="counter++" *ngIf="counter > 2"></child4-component>
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you mean something like:

```
<child1-component *ngFor="let child of children"></child1-component>
```

```
class MyComponent {
  children:any[] = [];

  load() {
    Observable.interval(1000).take(5).subscribe(e => this.children.push(e));
  }
}
```

If you want to add different components, you can use an approach like [Angular 2 dynamic tabs with user-click chosen components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468)