# Angular 6: Load multiple module on same page with Lazy Loading

Tags: angular, angular6, lazy-loading, angular-routing

I have an app where i want to lazy load multiple modules in the same page one by one so that i can reduce page load time (like in my dashboard page) with the same route path.

**My app-routing.modules.ts file:**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'dashboard',
      loadChildren: './dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'
    },
    { path:'dashboard', 
      loadChildren: () => UserlistComponent, pathMatch:'full' 
    },
    { path:'dashboard', 
      loadChildren: () => ClientlistComponent, pathMatch:'full' 
    },
    { path: '', 
    loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomeModule'
    },
```

**My dashboard-routing.modules.ts file would look like this :**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: DashboardComponent,
  },
];
```

i cant' find anyway to do it like this : i want to load both component(user list and client list lazi loaded one by one so that i can reduce page load time ) when user redirect on dashboard page.

there is similar stackoverflow question ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46234130/angular-4-load-components-one-by-one)) to this but i want to load component with lazy loading concept
[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular 4: load components one by one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46234130/angular-4-load-components-one-by-one)

Comment: No i want lazy loading, its different

Comment: As Alex said, you're already lazy loading the modules. Lazy loading is just not requiring everything to load at once. As [this test](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5xuid1) shows, an *ngIf that defaults to false will not initialize a component until it is set to true, so it is essentially the lazy loading you are looking for.

Comment: you mean to say my <app-user-list></app-user-list> and <app-client-list></app-client-list> will be load one by one if i do as per Alex answer - @ColbyHunter

Comment: Essentially, and if you wanted to be real picky about loading (like which loads first), the method shown in the question that I marked as the reason your post is a duplicate allows another layer of lazy loading.

Comment: look, basically i just want to display some components visible to user (like user list is visible now) at the same time the other component on the same page being start loading (like client list is loading now...)

Comment: Have you tried the method described in the post? That's exactly what it is doing.

Comment: just have a look on my question again. I have added expected output image.

Comment: @luckyamit were you able to find the answer to this ?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it you should probably import your UserList and ClientList components in the dashboard module. If you need them in the same page, then you should call them directly from your dashboard component template. Basically the loadChildren property when loading your dashboard module is already performing the lazy loading you seem to aiming for.

That would give you this for the app routes:

```js
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'dashboard',
      loadChildren: './dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'
    },
    { path: '', 
    loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomeModule'
    }
];
```

Keep the dashboard routing as is, but just place your UserListComponent and ClientListComponent in the dashboard folder and import them in the dashboard module, before calling them in the dashboard component template.

```js
// Dashboard module

import { UserListComponent } from '@dashboard/user-list/user-list.component';
import { ClientListComponent } from '@dashboard/client-list/client-list.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations : [
    UserListComponent,
    ClientListComponent,
  ] 
})
export class DashboardModule {}
```

```html
<!-- Dashboard component -->

<h1> Dashboard </h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">
    <app-user-list></app-user-list>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
    <app-client-list></app-client-list>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how  <app-user-list></app-user-list> and <app-client-list></app-client-list> will lazy loaded, only dashboard is lazy loaded but i also want userlist and clientlist component to be loaded lazy @Alex

Comment: I understood you want them to be displayed at the same time, in that case there's no need for lazy loading. Another approach would be to make a module for each component, but it seems a bit heavy and will prevent you from displaying them at the same time.

Comment: i don't want them to be load at same time i just want to be load one by one first load user list then client list and so on.. so that user can view at least user list during the client list is loading and so on.

Comment: just have a look on my question again. i have added expected output image

Comment: It as to do with data management then, asynchronous loading can be performed with observables and a well designed API. You can use boolean flags and *ngIf to display a component once its data are fully loaded

Answer (score 0):

I had the same concern, I had a dashboard module that had 5 sections of which 4 were carrucel with mat-card components full of images. What I did was simulate lazy loading with these components using * ngIf. Create a state where all components had load = false and based on. AfterViewInit life cycle each component was set to true the next so on. And so the initial low load and the user experience improved. It's something similar to Perform Promises in series.